# Specify preload/create functions when instantiating Phaser.Game

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework

According to [phaser.io/tutorials](https://phaser.io/tutorials/how-to-use-phaser-with-typescript), you can set a initial `preload`/`create` function for the game instance:

```
this.game = new Phaser.Game(800, 600, Phaser.AUTO, 'content', { preload: this.preload, create: this.create });
```

However, I'm trying to pass these constructor arguments as an object instead:

```
SceneContainers.phaserGame = new Phaser.Game({
    width: ProjectSettings.resolution[0],
    height: ProjectSettings.resolution[1],
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    parent: 'content',
    backgroundColor: ProjectSettings.backgroundColor,
    // 'preload: ...' and 'create: ...' do not exist here
    // Also, 'callbacks: ...' does not support 'preload: ...' and 'create: ...'
    // according to TypeScript completions.
});
```

To which property does belong `preload`/`create`? When I look at the API docs, I search for `preload` and nothing shows up: [Phaser.Game](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.55.2/Phaser.Game) and [Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig](https://newdocs.phaser.io/docs/3.52.0/Phaser.Types.Core.GameConfig).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: **Yes**, it does exist. It is the property `scene`.

```
var config = {
    ...
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    scene: { preload, create},
    ...
};
```

*Althought, that property can be set with other data types.*

***Minor Update:** In the official tutorial section, there are several nice examples, on how this property can be used https://phaser.io/examples/v3/category/scenes, I still consult these examples, when I have to write phaser apps/code.*